# IDA binary patch "has no file mapping"

Tags: ida, patching, binary-editing

I am trying to change one byte (TBZ to TBNZ) inside a ~40mb binary. Ive done this multiple times with other files but this time IDA is giving me a hard time by simply not patching and printing this to the console:

```
71007A5BCF: has no file mapping (original: 36 patched: 37)...skipping...
Applied 0/1 patch(es)
```

[image]

I am unable to figure out what it means and how to fix it. If someone does, please tell me in layman's terms as english is not my primary language.